# How to handle serial mutations with react apollo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I have a small question about how to properly handle mutations in Apollo for React.

**Situation**

I want to set a state of the component after a successful mutation — but before setting the state I want to perform other mutation (using `@client`). Mutations return promises so my first attempt was to **chain promises**, but then I realize that the remote mutation could take a long time and a user could go to another page and when the promise resolves my component will be **unmounted** already.

At the moment I consider 2 approaches to solve the issue:

1. To use **EventEmitter** and emit an event on mutation finish. Subscribe at `componentDidMount` and unsubscribe on `componentWillUnmount`.
2. To use **cancelable promises** - this recommended ( https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html ) in React docs, but it is not a standard and looks a bit "hackish", especially on promise chains.

But I feel that there should be a **better way**, thanks in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're trying to do. If the user navigates away and the component unmounts, even using the 2 solutions above will not affect the component's state when it's mounted again -- it's state will be reset to whatever the initial state is set up to be. It sounds like you should be lifting the state up to a component that won't be affected by user navigation, or using something like redux to manage app state.

Comment: The idea is to handle the case when a component is already unmounted when the mutation is resolved.